# How do I install OpenMW?

Tags: games, software-installation

[OpenMW](https://openmw.org/) seems like a great game, and it reboots a classic, but What is it exactly, and how do I Install it?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

[OpenMW](https://openmw.org/) is an game engine based on that of [Morrowind](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/The_Elder_Scrolls_III:_Morrowind), an RPG game from 2002. Although its still in Alpha, it works. It and its editor(OpenCS) has been written completely from scratch. Do you like Morrowind? then you are gonna love OpenMW.

Before we begin:

> Playing Morrowind with this engine still requires one to own the Morrowind data files.

Meaning if you have installed Morrowind via wine, you can Invoke the dash, search for OpenMW, select the Morrowind data files, and then play the game. This was such in my case.

> You do need to own Morrowind to play using OpenMW. OpenMW looks for a directory on your system containing the 'Data Files' section of an existing installation of Morrowind. That 'Data Files' folder contains all of the art assets and game data from Morrowind and is the only thing OpenMW needs to be playable. It has become difficult to find a retail copy of Morrowind, but it is currently available on Steam and that version works just as well.

### Install

I will show you guys how to install OpenMW using the PPA and compiling option. And as we go will provide download links for the Windows/Mac os x equivalent.

#### PPA

By far the easiest way is installing via it's official [PPA](https://launchpad.net/%7Eopenmw/+archive/openmw), it supports a variety of distros. Users that are running Windows, can go [here](http://downloads.openmw.org/windows/), and download the latest OpenMW. As for Mac, the following link will provide dmg's: [come and get me](http://downloads.openmw.org/osx/).

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:openmw/openmw
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install openmw
```

Invoke the dash, search for OpenMW select the Morrowind data files, and the play the game.

---

#### From source

Usually - on a Linux machine - when you want the latest features, you compile the application yourself, which is what we are gonna do. For compiling it in a different OS then Linux, Mac or Windows, see there official wiki: [Development Environment Setup - OpenMW Wiki](https://wiki.openmw.org/index.php?title=Development_Environment_Setup)

#### Dependencies

Add the OpenMW PPA to download the needed dependencies: `sudo add-apt-repository ppa:openmw/openmw`, after that refresh your sources list: `sudo apt-get update`

```
sudo apt-get install git libopenal-dev libogre-1.9-dev \
libsdl2-dev libqt4-dev libboost-filesystem-dev libboost-thread-dev \
libboost-wave-dev libboost-chrono-dev libboost-program-options-dev \
libboost-system-dev libav-tools libavcodec-dev libavformat-dev \
libavutil-dev libswscale-dev \
libbullet-dev libmygui-dev libunshield-dev libtinyxml-dev cmake build-essential
```

#### Compile

Then we configure, compile, and install OpenMW.

```
mkdir build
cd build
cmake ../
make
```

And your done.
[image]
<sup>Personal Pick</sup>

### Source:

Excerpt from:

- [How do I install OpenMW - EuroBytes](http://www.eurobytes.nl/tutorials/how-do-i-install-openmw)

Which I am the author of.